# Emgu CV cannot create an image from given path

Tags: c#, emgucv

When I load image from given path:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> source = new Image<Bgr, byte>(absoluteImagePath);
```

Where absolute path is: 

`D:\Users\Oijafaosfasdf\Source\Workspaces\SomeProject\SomeProjectV3\SomeProject.UI\bin\Debug\636260785130864402.png`

It throws weird exception:

First time:

[image: weird exception 1]

All other times when try to create image without terminating the program:

[image: weird exception 2]

> --- Start of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   
> The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   The path is not of a legal form.    at
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)    at
>   System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)    at
>   System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)    at
>   Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.LoadUnmanagedModules(String loadDirectory, String[]
>   unmanagedModules)    at
>   Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.DefaultLoadUnmanagedModules(String[] modules)    at
>   Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

This is not dublicate to this -> [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206179/emgu-cv-image-load-notworking) question, as I have absolute path provided.
I already checked that file format is valid and file exists in directory..
So, what could go wrong?

**Note:** I'm installing Emgu CV (v3.1.0.1) using Nuget package manager.

Comment: have you tried it with a simpler path? e.g. `D:\test`

Comment: @ThomasMoors Just tried, still the same.

Comment: Thats a shame, what about double backslashes?

Comment: Did you try to open the file without emgu? Like `new FileInfo(@"yourpath")` or `var exist = File.Exists(@"yourpath")` or `File.OpenRead(@"yourpath")`. The problem is not Emgu but your file path. Sometime you can have a not visible character in the string.

Comment: @Kalten Yes, I tried `new FileInfo(@"mypath").Exists` and everything seemed fine. It looks like there may be something with installation, because this looks suspicious. I remember when I used openCV using Nuget package manager, nothing worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of staring at the same error message, I realized, that the problem is with dlls, they cannot be found. As I had already installed **Costura.Fody** package that merges all dlls into an executable, that was the reason why *Emgu CV* *was not working at all..* Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Image<bgr, byte> source = new Image<bgr, byte>("D://Users//Oijafaosfasdf//Source//Workspaces//SomeProject//SomeProjectV3//SomeProject.UI//bin//Debug//636260785130864402.png");
```

Or try to load any other image, if it works maybe the image you are trying to load has corrupt headers.

Comment: Tried using uri path and other images/formats, still the same.. Could there be problem with nuget installation?

Comment: Have you tried loading to a `Bitmap` object and pass it to the Image instead of the absolute path?

Comment: Created bitmap successfully using given path, although still the same error when step onto Emgu CV code.. Do you have the same error or this is only for me?

Comment: If `Image<bgr, byte> source = new Image<bgr, byte>(YourBitmapObject);` still gives you error, your Emgu installation may be corrupted.

Comment: By creating new console application and adding Emgu CV it works. But when I do the same for my other project (Class library) it fails. For all solutions I set x64 architecture. Other thing is that it runs asynchronously, although I'm using static method and class..